# Convolution Theorem and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

How do I prove that $F(f(x)g(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\tilde{f}(k)*\tilde{g}(k)$?

Comment: Standard result: use Fubini's theorem to change integration order.

Comment: The identity is not correct: it's the inverse Fourier Transform of $f(x)g(x)$. See my asnwer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F, G$ the Fourier Transform of $f$ and $g$. The choice of the coefficient follows by how one defines the Fourier Transform. I will avoid id, according to my definition, but the results are the same.

Now:

\begin{align*}
F(u)G(u) & = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2\pi i u x}\ \text{d}x\right) G(u)\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2\pi i u x} G(u)\ \text{d}x
\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(y-x) e^{-i 2\pi u y}\ \text{d}y\right)\text{d}x \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) g(y-x)\ \text{d}x \right)e^{-2\pi i u y}\text{d}y
\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (f(x)*g(x)) e^{-2\pi i u y}\ \text{d}y
\\
& = \mathcal{F}\left({f(x)*g(x)}\right)
\end{align*}

Now you can read the proof backwards, operating with the inverse Fourier Transform to obtain what you asked for:

$$\underbrace{\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{F}\left(f(x)*g(x)\right)\right)}_{\equiv f(x)*g(x)} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(F(u)G(u)\right)$$

That is

$$ f(x)*g(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(F(u)G(u)\right)$$